# jQuery validation onblur

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, onblur

I am trying to get the jQuery validation working on a webpage I am creating. I have about 6 different fieldsets that contain the page's details. I am using this as I am hiding and showing them give a better user experience.

I have the plugin working as I want whenever I try submit the page and whenever I add a single character (when a textbox requires 2 or more characters) however I also want the validation to happen onblur. I want to inform my users straight away if they haven't met the validation condition so they can fix it straight away and don't have to come back.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do I am using the  * http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ plugin.

This is the jQuery code I have written so far:

```
      $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            rules: {
            <%=txtFirstName.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
                ,
                <%=txtSurname.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
                ,
                <%=txtMobileNumber.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                }
                ,
                <%=Email.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
                ,
                   <%=ddDay.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true

                }
                ,
                   <%=ddMonth.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true

                }
                ,
                   <%=ddYear.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true

                }
                ,
                <%=txtHouseNumber.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:1

                }
                ,
                <%=txtAddress1.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:5
                }
                ,
                <%=txtCity.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:2
                }
                ,
                <%=txtSuburb.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:2
                }
                ,
                <%=txtPostCode.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:4,
                    maxlength:4
                }

                 ,
                <%=UserName.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:4

                }
                ,
                <%=Password.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength:4

                }
                ,
                 <%=ConfirmPassword.UniqueID %>:
                {
                   equalTo: "ctl00$ctl00$cpMain$cpLeft$Password"

                }
                  ,
                <%=chkTerms.UniqueID %>:
                {
                    required: true


                }

            },
            messages: {
                <%=txtFirstName.UniqueID %>:
            {
                required: "Please enter your firstname",
                minlength: "Minimum length is 2 characters"
            },
               <%=txtSurname.UniqueID %>:
            {
                required: "Please enter your lastname",
                minlength: "Minimum length is 2 characters"
            },
            <%=txtMobileNumber.UniqueID %>:
            {
                required: "Please enter your mobile",
                minlength: "Minimum length is 8 characters"
            }
            ,
            <%=ddDay.UniqueID %>:
            {
                required: "Please enter your date of birth"

            }
            ,
            <%=txtMobileNumber.UniqueID %>:
            {
                  required: "Please enter your date of birth"
            }
            ,
            <%=txtMobileNumber.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your date of birth"
            }
            ,
                  <%=Email.UniqueID %>: 
                  "Please enter a valid email"
            ,
            <%=txtHouseNumber.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your house number",
                   minlength:"Please add at least 1 character"
            }

             ,
            <%=txtAddress1.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your address",
                   minlength:"Please add at least 5 characters"
            }
            ,
            <%=txtCity.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your city",
                   minlength:"Please add at least 2 characters"
            }
            ,
            <%=txtSuburb.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your city",
                   minlength:"Please add at least 2 characters"
            }
             ,
            <%=txtPostCode.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your postcode",
                   minlength:"Please add the 4 required characters",
                   maxlength:"Only 4 characters are allowed"
            }
             ,
            <%=UserName.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your username",
                   minlength: "Please add the 4 required characters"

            }
             ,
            <%=Password.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please enter your password",
                   minlength: "Please add the 4 required characters"

            }
             ,
            <%=ConfirmPassword.UniqueID %>:
            {
                  equalTo: "Passwords must match"
             }
            ,
            <%=chkTerms.UniqueID %>:
            {
                   required: "Please agree to the terms"


            }

           }


        });
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't see anything in the docos that can do that. The only other way i can think of doing it is.

```
$('#field1, #field2, #field3').blur(function(){
    validator.validate()
});
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, Cool so I am not going mad. what is validator ? do you mean      $("#aspnetForm").validate(); instead of validator.validate()

Comment: yea that one. lol my mistake. you can create a validator object(though you are not, and you don't need to).

Comment: It can be done.......just need to add this onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); } ,   works a treat

Comment: Actually, `onfocusout: function(element) { this.element(element); }` is the best way, as per the plugin's own internal code.

Answer (score 54):

Diver Dan was right

```
$('form').validate({
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    rules: {
        name: 'required',
        from: 'required'

    },
    messages: {
        name: 'Please enter your firstname',
        from: 'Please enter where are you from'
    }
});
```

Comment: I had to add "onkeyup: false," to get the desired behavior

Comment: Actually, it would be better to use same method that's used within the plugin.   So...  `this.element(element)` instead of `$(element).valid()`.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16205614/594235

Comment: This gives Uncaught TypeError: validator.settings[eventType].call is not a function

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the element call of the validator.

```
   $('form').validate({
        onfocusout: function(element) {
           this.element(element);
        },
        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            from: 'required'

        },
        messages: {
            name: 'Please enter your firstname',
            from: 'Please enter where are you from'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set on onkeyup = false

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: 'required',
        from: 'required'

    },
      onkeyup: false
       ,
    messages: {
        name: 'Please enter your firstname',
        from: 'Please enter where are you from'
    }
});
```

Comment: **This is actually the correct answer!** Solved my problem of quick validation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Thia code will not fire validation onkeyup, but on blur "lost
>   focus" the validation will be fire, as will once the user starts to edit the field, validation message will disappear. find more interesting other customization on this ref:
>   https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/

```
$('#frm').validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            focusCleanup: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
onkeyup: function (element, event) {

 $(element).valid();
 // your code
}
```